# Regex: Capture only numbers with a X-XXXXX-XXXXX pattern (Skip unwanted characters)?

Tags: asp.net, regex, pattern-matching

I have a number of `0-12345-67890` and I want to capture `0123456789` in a named capture group.  I got this far:

```
@"(?<upc>\d-\d{5}-\d{5})"
```

Which captures the string as-is.  How do you skip the dashes while grabbing the number as a single named group?  BTW, this is ASP.NET Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with a regex match to a single backreference. Either you match the dashes, or you don't (and capture nothing).

You'll have to remove them manually with `Replace()` after capturing the numbers:

```
var number = m.Groups["upc"].Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: That's amazing.  I would think extracting 1234.56 out of $1,234.56 would be common.

Comment: Well that is possible to do, just don't include '$' in the match. In your case your your match has '-' separating components of it...

Comment: Replace or concatenation would be the only way to do it.  Each RegEx matche is contiguous sub-strings.  You are asking to skip characters in a contiguous sub-string and still have it come out as a match.

Comment: Yep, the keyword here is "contiguous".

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You either capture in 3 groups and concatenate them into a single string, or do a search-and-replace to get rid of the dashes in your single named group.